# How to update client-side packages in ASP .NET Core 2.1?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

Environment: .NET Core 2.1 running on Ubuntu 18.04

When a new ASP .NET core project is created, a bunch of client-side packages are automatically generated. For example:

```
$ dotnet new razor
$ ls wwwrooot/lib

bootstrap  jquery  jquery-validation  jquery-validation-unobtrusive
```

However, I do not see any configuration file that lists these client-side packages.

I believe bower is no longer being used. Plus, I don't see any `bower.json` file.

I believe libman is not even present on my machine. Plus, I don't see any `libman.json` file.

Using the command `dotnet restore` restores only the .net packages listed in `.csproj` file but does not restore packages under `wwwroot/lib` directory.

As a quick test, I deleted `wwwroot/lib` directory and tried various commands. However, none of my attempts was able to restore any packages under `wwwroot/lib` directory.

Can someone please tell me how are client-side packages managed in ASP.NET Core 2.1 and beyond? How does one upgrade these packages to the latest version?

Comment: They're just hardcoded in the template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the files in projects created with the `dotnet new` command are simply hard-coded in the template. So if you delete them the only way to get them back would be to copy them in from somewhere else.

If you want to manage client-side libraries, then you can use any number of tools to help you such as [`LibMan`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/libman/?view=aspnetcore-2.1) or one of the many third-party alternatives.